WebToCase form is not generating cases in Salesforce
We have a VF page for Web to Case form.
when we click on submit, case is not getting created. Request is getting queued.
Getting debug logs as below.
Your request has been queued.
Record Information:
00N3M000006ynnq: Deepa
00N3M000006ynnr: 1234
00N3M000006ynnu: Generator
00N3M000006ynnv:
00N3M000006ynnx: Delhi
00N3M000006ynny: India
00N3M000006ynnz: Delhi
00N3M000006yno0: 110068
00N3M000006yno1: Test , Test123
00N3M000006yno6: 1
captcha_settings: {"keyname":"TER_WebToCaseKey","fallback":"true","orgId":"******","ts":"1723097432708"}
debug: 1
debugEmail: ****m
email: *****
encoding: UTF-8
g-recaptcha-response: 03AFcWeA5xl1iLhIWtV_6q-g6ZU9XeearaE8fUA0qRT051UzsPo6h9U7FOOlb4h6sl-t_48QR-vm6LP857jMT5Ici2ciqrPivH-uA5-I_sXr4IafkgPuv_X5LWvHfZ27Ek-VIiMyTzod1s7Oz2wlilqJmZbkrjYYGhCLByjfHI-x8MGPggN_hNQxRifNNdm9AW0DDsWpL9OSTpXGuGHf9M0h6WhmbbZtG2WP2Ikl7O9Ey-krdSHeZzz8a-TKLoN1tQQMk_6MRM14oRsAlDplwRE7GZI4rHCkvBPMteBRfl0KX6p5XjQ7GNSA0-YO87ZJsvcjcrN2sLHlzp5x21OzUtna4gnYLOh6c1NxRFrmBUjDDrh5YXdzoLfkxsuq1Vz_HqOgg6EBDbsXaiirYmtYYptEwPc6gPnuBBXqa2rsFgbEzI9jRvWbAyvd0XhLR70p5V7KSnBatKRDxmL7ZVtirDmW7nHpovlejTWBnNc5u3Qakv8gxStbV6COd0zKLw7kkWKLFwMMZ3tn-qoIA3rhwTMSKW1-ek-iwDRU2v8m-FeN8ES5HKkcL3GsNE2I2ob5kmJK7YMvCY8NSv5glurJJVp7hM2PsyJkPRJxq6evMK8Jq-MyWU-A9NZQgpYA8jwSLFbuyD1oCQhxgC2Nu-IDSsG-Oa7J-wqLaVjPlTr2vPT3uBO_Rq9eLjrPl1SUM8bdJuTrHJJ0yGf5GNo1_HENuFNpu2K3v6Z_bz6I5YsYVe7cBpcFRnj2ichBNmsqvv0ri-lIf9jeh03trZWErA4KQxUBJRd-WcmzP4g3C759wf8p0trdhRQoOznNwq8JP5F_qHQ5sQ2_c1KIOEPFpH3dRQDBZQKSR2sYTCmndxKb3ONE4V3-iyEFf-onUV_XrV8Pd8ZeCTJbXJPbWAGMWHO1LhUc3J_hDDFcn9yZbzKa97tgD-EXqiCpuqVvfdtJBFtGRXDyiQR37Cc9IGxDb400ZKtKmDFnCSeMchmAkbbu0Pq51RZsk9z8HaZ8GTYvsFmTW_hj2Fh5t1vEUHAk4Es-lWcw1PpSfbA9fVgumpokzQ8joRjKvI48XhU8kr1uQ-WOBS7gFwfwDk4a4ft7Wbmwt3fzSvkkr_MxeEUw2ptKvQevbs3dINlidv3_AyZjESJLATZFY2zM8ulTtLkqclHFOYCScRw4oF2S7OfHiVw3kJYdYaqTJ1_74mSFBM_w5fpGPrYVmEuvwEslwlncdf0wJ54CFRKHs3Hco15k6GbAOrsjRZgxC43DBhWXb_twz_OhcawsTGPCfxiqgGlfmlqQBq8biPbfmkjbWGPE88YlhlsjikBGoONJvwcXEowBinOf40E_z0SgwmtM8AfRwLxP7srGQDJDUuOzDDeyBfT47hwjYo6ycCPOFVn53DWDuuzXddZv_Q-kTJbue2zkLs-NNm7QX-C9y3FklNv8Af22GtGj9NQhpKq2WpMt7q0WSqztkFnbA4G8XxAXmZhjrcbwC5X0uOMxPl1u7GKJuO9DBhcgu5VMfv3T7VeffXgjo_8oqt1rXktwowvZrqa_R9hp44DYCuPxaxNqJuC2PT_cKKd9df_NNLt8b6oNxbti9_nfOvRvW6_PCoFZ4I9D8C_rINv0uH9luyqjOI847gdNvXA2gEZ459dXRustFbt798lG-TOXc-44AAXfb9_VMIuA5BU8Gy9ogVEjMUVu3SSKH65FD4djWsC-iunRhZrb1AwOIvppsWj8ajyq_l0wy8ow-lg_SAgMGHcUp_lbDJCJogMHqhXez-TgNyNQWCM6btRssvldM1FkC_ligeM62vs2FC6_JAUtTABRawUWujF0uREK3TQ6QR8sfFPokkLX8pXp5_1YQhF63_EU96UUQaPHIwk8yv7FXV_Y3ppHEgojLN6jY-wUOgtVoerYSPJHn_66xBeawdJASBAs30-og9-4KC9geJb-lWTuB-rnPnNsOgvGAyaJlpLM2_MqA
name: Deepa Anand
orgid: ******
phone: *****
recordType: 0123M000000tpsKQAQ
retURL:
https:****
sitekey: 6LcFehwqAAAAALs8n4-WPktnSUkXnCqQz-__IxjP
submit: Register
termsandservices:
*********


Refer to this: -https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8ezgSAB

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.web_to_case_html.htm&type=5
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customizesupport_web_to_case_notes.htm&type=5


Not helpful.... I have checked already

The documentation that clearly states that  requests over the limit are queued.

Though the same link has been already shared in comment above. Let me know what is not helpful in the link.
In a 24-hour period, you can capture up to 5,000 cases. If you reach this limit, any additional requests are placed in a pending request queue, which handles both Web-to-Case and Web-to-Lead submissions.
This has been documented in webtolead guidelines here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customizesupport_web_to_case_notes.htm&type=5

You can capture up to 5,000 cases in a 24-hour period. When you reach the 24-hour limit, additional requests are stored in a pending request queue that contains both Web-to-Case and Web-to-Lead requests. The default case owner listed on the Support Settings page receives an email containing the additional case information, and the requests are submitted when the limit refreshes. If a new case can’t be generated due to errors in your Web-to-Case setup, Customer Support is notified so that we can help you fix it.
The pending request queue has a limit of 50,000 combined requests. If your organization reaches the pending request limit, additional requests are rejected and not queued. The administrator receives email notifications for the first five rejected submissions.
Contact Salesforce Customer Support to request an increase to your daily case limit or pending request limit.

